# Setting values on child scope with jquery-menu-aim

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm working on creating a directive for [jQuery-menu-aim](https://github.com/kamens/jQuery-menu-aim), and my current implementation is working, but finding and setting values on the child scope feels like a hack.

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/lqcoJj?p=preview

```
var rowScope = angular.element(row).find('.contentAim').scope();
```

I'm looking for a cleaner, or more angular-ish way of accomplishing this. Ideally not having to use a jQuery selector get the child scope.

Comment: I haven't gone through your example thoroughly, but you could use `scope.$broadcast` to emit an event from you `menuAim` directive to its children. In the children, listen for this event using `scope.$on`, and perform updates as needed. You'd need to pass some identifier to event listeners indicating which row should be updated.

Comment: Ah @bibs interesting, I am taking someone's advice and doing that, but the opposite direction. If no one posts I'll put my solution up as community wiki.

Comment: I have done a similar thing in the past. Placing properties on the scope can incur noticeable latency in program processing (anything on the current scope will be dirty-checked in the $digest cycle). Events, though not as convenient, allow precise control over directive to directive communication.

Comment: @JasonMore what event are you listening on in the children to trigger the `emit` to the parent?

Comment: @bibs in link, I'm sending an event to a parent scope to add it's scope to an array, so the parent scope can do things to all child elements.

Comment: @JasonMore there's probably a cleaner solution using controllers. If you post your updated plunkr I can give it a shot.

Comment: @bibs its updated. I couldn't find a way around the .scope() issue, but use $emit for other bits now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this solution: http://plnkr.co/edit/pvycJi?p=preview

It circumvents the need to update child scopes directly or emit events.